# How to sum overlapping interval parts in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, intervals

I have 2 tables of Time Intervals. One being a schedule the other being sign in and outs of the system. I need to see overlapping intervals and sum the parts where they are overlapping. Is there an efficient way to do this. I am currently trying the below. But it does not work when the Sign in and outs start before and after the segment. Meaning they were signed in for the whole time of the segment. It currently returns 0 when it should be the entire segment time. I know I am doing this wrong trying to see if there is a pattern I should be following. The SQL is confusing this I believe.. This is what I am trying to sum:

[image: OverlappingSegments]

This SQL gets the segments that overlap. Now that I have them I need the select piece to sum the overlapping pieces. I don't know if there is one equation that will do it.

```
FROM SCRD.APEMPSTAT
INNER JOIN AMS.EwfmSegmentData
ON SCRD.APEMPSTAT.Resource_XID = AMS.EwfmSegmentData.Resource_XID
    AND SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignIn < AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StopDate
    AND SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignOut > AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StartDate
INNER JOIN SCRD.SEGAP
ON AMS.EwfmSegmentData.CODE = SCRD.SEGAP.CODE
WHERE persp_ap = 'NO'
```

Comment: I would recommend looking up the term Aliasing. It will make your code much more readable and will therefore make help easier to find.

Comment: Zane I am actually in the other camp. I often think aliasing leads to code that is harder to read. Especially for one who is familiar with the original tables. For the purpose of help I would agree maybe aliasing or in this case just spoofing table names might have helped. In reality this question was more a theoretical question then an SQL question and I shouldn't have included my bad SQL to confuse. Thank you for the comment I do appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @dstigue You just love using your fingers, don't you

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I am not sure what you are referring to but yes mostly for counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over my own image. I think I solved it. The SQL looks like this.

```
DATEDIFF(s, CASE 
        WHEN Startdate > SignIn
            THEN StartDate
        ELSE SignIn
        END, CASE 
        WHEN StopDate < SignOut
            THEN StopDate
        ELSE Signout
        END)
```

This boils down to The lesser of B and Y minus the greater of A or X. I just went one by one and made the equation that I would use:
1. B-X
2. Y-A
3. Y-X
4. B-A
From that I realized that the begininning was always B or Y and the minus part was always X or A. Then I looked at why I picked each. Hence the lesser and greater piece. I hope this can help someone else out there. That datediff piece is I want the gap in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of

```
AND SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignIn < AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StopDate
AND SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignOut > AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StartDate
```

in your join and do it in the WHERE clause just to make it more readable.

Here's what I would put in your WHERE:

```
AND ((SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignIn 
        BETWEEN AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StartDate AND AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StopDate) OR
     (SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignOut 
        BETWEEN AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StartDate AND AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StopDate) OR
     (SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignIn < AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StartDate AND
       SCRD.APEMPSTAT.SignOut > AMS.EwfmSegmentData.StopDate))
```

I am sure there is a way to get rid of some of it but this should get the records you are looking for.

Comment: "Readable" is subjective - if you're going after readability, why wouldn't you suggest aliases? Also those seem to be join conditions, not filters, so if it were me, I'd leave them right where they are.

Comment: The records I get are fine. The issue is in the summing. I want to sum the overlapping parts. It returns properly. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: I guess my head wasn't on straight yesterday.  You are right.  Your join criteria did return all the rows.  I don't know what I was thinking.